# Amazon lex unexpected error and unknown error

Tags: amazon-web-services, drag-and-drop, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I have a program in **Amazon Lex**. It is a basic program at one part where I use a conditional the second track displays the error (error for the bot) here is the part of that program:

[image: Amazon Lex configuration]

**Error in code:**

[image: Error in code]

**Error in with chatbot:**

[image: Error in with chatbot]

Also while building the chat bot there is no error occurring its only while testing it out the expected output is not coming. As far as I can tell input values by the user and in the program are matching with the slots